# Row separator after using AWK

Tags: shell-script, awk

```
awk -F ';' '{print $1}' FileName
```

I am using this command to print the first column of a file which is semi colon delimited.

Now, I have to loop through the output of above command.
If my output is

```
0
1
2
```

I have to loop through each record and I have to specify the iteration what is my record delimiter in my output

Is there a way to print the output something like below

```
0;1;2
```

So that I can iterate saying the delimiter is ;

Comment: would be better if you add sample input also... piping the output to `paste -sd\;` would be an option too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to avoid trailling semicolon

```
 awk -F\; 'NR>1 { printf ";" ;} {printf "%s",$1;} END {printf "\n"} '
```

- `printf` don't print line feed
- `NR>1` only print after first line
- `END` print after last line.

Comment: Thank you so much..That helped in removing the trailing semicolon

Answer (score 2):

`awk` outputs the value of `ORS` (output record separator) at the end of each `print` statements. It's a newline by default, but you can change it:

```
$ cat foo.txt
0;3;6
1;4;7
2;5;8
$ awk -vORS=';' -F';' '{print $1} END {printf "\n"}'  foo.txt
0;1;2;
```

I added the `END {printf "\n"}` to get a newline at the end of output.

Answer (score 0):

You could also go with coreutils:

```
<foo.txt cut -d';' -f1 | paste -sd';'
```